If $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a decreasing differentiable function, prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^4 f(x)=0$.
I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a decreasing differentiable function such that $f(0)=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ and $\int_0^{\infty}x^4f'(x)dx < \infty$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^4 f(x)=0$.

I tried to use a technique that I saw in another problem: Because $f$ is decreasing and $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, we know that $f$ is nonnegative. If we have that
$\int_0^{\infty}x^3f(x)dx < \infty$ and $x>0$, then
\begin{align}
0&\leq (5^{1/4}x)^4f(5^{1/4}x) = 5x^4f(5^{1/4}x) = 5f(5^{1/4}x) \int_x^{5^{1/4}x} t^3dt = 5 \int_x^{5^{1/4}x} t^3f(5^{1/4}x)dt \leq \\ &\leq 5 \int_x^{5^{1/4}x} t^3f(t)dt = 5\left(  \int_0^{5^{1/4}x} t^3f(t)dt - \int_0^{x} t^3f(t)dt\right)\to 0 \text{ as } x\to\infty.
\end{align}
Notice that we used the hypothesis that $f$ is decreasing in the inequality. By taking $u=5^{1/4}x$, we finish the proof.
However, I don't know how to prove that $\int_0^{\infty}x^3f(x)dx$ is finite with the given hypothesis.

Since $f$ is decreasing, $f'<0$. Did you mean to assume $\int_0^\infty x^4f'(x)dx>-\infty$?

The condition $x^4f(x)\to c$ is equivalent to $\int x^3f(x),dx $ convergent.

For $0\le a<b$ applying integration by parts gives
$$-\int\limits_a^bx^4f'(x)\,dx =-x^4f(x)\Big\vert_a^b+\int\limits_a^b4x^3f(x)\,dx \\ \ge [a^4f(a)-b^4f(b)]+f(b)\int\limits_a^b4x^3\,dx \\ =
[a^4f(a)-b^4f(b)]+[b^4-a^4]f(b)=a^4[f(a)-f(b)]$$
Taking the limit when $b\to\infty$ gives $$
-\int\limits_a^\infty x^4f'(x)\,dx \ge a^4f(a)$$ The limit of LHS when $a\to \infty$ is equal $0.$ Hence the conclusion follows.
Remark
As a side effect we get the convergence of $\int\limits_0^\infty x^3f(x)\,dx.$ Indeed the first formula with $a=0$ yields $$-\int\limits_0^bx^4f'(x)\,dx =-x^4f(x)\Big\vert_0^b+\int\limits_0^b4x^3f(x)\,dx $$ Taking the limit when $b\to \infty $ implies the convergence and gives the identity
$$-\int\limits_0^\infty x^4f'(x)\,dx =\int\limits_0^\infty 4x^3f(x)\,dx $$

Since $f$ is decreasing $f'<0$, so the LHS is negative. See also my comment on the question.

LHS doesn't have to be positive. For exmaple $f=1/(1+x^5)$.

@J.G.  I have mixed up the signs

@J.G. Should be fine now.

@RyszardSzwarc Thank you, very nice idea. With this argument it is not necessary to assume that $f(0)=1$, right?

The value at $0$ is meaningless. But WLOG we may assume $f(0)=1$  replacing $f$ by $f/f(0).$
